# Spring MVC app + Hibernate = GenericJDBCException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate and Spring - entity with multiple members inheriting from same parent causes JDBCException, @Transactional weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809543/hibernate-and-spring-entity-with-multiple-members-inheriting-from-same-parent)

### I have reformated this question into SSCCE - **[See the reformatted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809543/hibernate-and-spring-entity-with-multiple-members-inheriting-from-same-parent)**

I'm having a problem with my spring webmvc project, which uses Hibernate via JPA. The application models college courses, students, assignments, announcements, and students comments on those assignments and announcements (and much more, but these are the relevant entities for this question)

Section entity:

```
@Entity
public class Section {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Assignment> assignments = new HashSet<Assignment>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Announcement> announcements = new HashSet<Announcement>();

    ... more properties, getters/setters, etc ...
```

Assignment and Announcement share a base class Commentable, which only has an auto-generated Id. The problem is, when I try to create a section and an an assignment within a transactional method, I get a **"org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update"** exception.

Here is the test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value = "classpath*:WEB-INF/spring-data.xml")
public class EntityPersistenceTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    SectionService sectionService;

    @Autowired
    DbTestData dbTestData;

    @Test
    public void Test() {
        dbTestData.persistTestData();
    }

    @After
    public void afterTest() {
        Section art = sectionService.byCourseSchoolIdYearSeason("art101", 2011, Semester.Season.fall);

        Assert.assertTrue(art.getAssignments().size() > 0);
        Assert.assertTrue(art.getAnnouncements().size() > 0);

        System.out.println("Test completed successfully.");
    }

}
```

Here is persistTestData, from DbTestData (which is annotated with Component)

```
@Transactional
public void persistTestData(){
    Course art = new Course("art101", "Art 101 - Basic Art", "General art class focusing on finger painting");
    Professor ron = new Professor("Ron", "Bier", "ron@school.edu", "ron", "password");
    Semester fall11 = new Semester(2011, Semester.Season.fall);
    Section section = new Section(art, fall11, "51024");

    entityManager.persist(art);
    entityManager.persist(ron);
    entityManager.persist(fall11);
    entityManager.persist(section);

    Date sevenDaysAway = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));

    section.addAssignment(new Homework(ron, new Date(), sevenDaysAway, true, "Art project 1"));
    section.addAnnouncement(new Announcement(ron, new Date(), "Announcement Text"));
}
```

Here is the full debug log from Hibernate and error code that happens while calling persistTestData:

```
Hibernate: insert into Course (id, description, schoolId, title) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: call identity()
Hibernate: insert into Person (id, email, enabled, first, last, passwordHash, username, DTYPE) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'Professor')
Hibernate: call identity()
Hibernate: insert into Semester (id, season, year) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: call identity()
Hibernate: insert into Section (id, active, course_id, sectionId, semester_id) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: call identity()
DEBUG: com.whiteboard.wb.data.entity.Assignment - Created a new Assignment with params
Hibernate: insert into Commentable (id, author_id, postDate, active, due, abstrct, DTYPE) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'Homework')
Hibernate: call identity()
Hibernate: insert into Person_authorities (Person_id, authorities) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Section_Commentable (Section_id, assignments_id) values (?, ?)
WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - failed batch
ERROR: org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.whiteboard.wb.data.sample.DbTestData$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ca8fb7f2.persist(<generated>)
    at entity.BigTest.Test(BigTest.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:199)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: failed batch
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 49 more
```

I've found three ways to fix this problem, none of which I really understand:

1. Have only one item extending Commentable in the Section entity. Removing the "Announcements" onetomany collection from Section (and the calls to it from the test) makes this error go away completely. Obviously I need to have multiple collections of different types of Commentables so this is unacceptable.
2. Annotate the @Test call with @Transactional. With identical code everywhere else, this completely fixes the problem, and both the Announcement and Homework get persisted correctly without errors.

   ```
   @Test
   @Transactional
   public void Test() {
       dbTestData.persist();
   }
   ```
3. Add the assignments and announcement in a different transaction than in the one where the section is being created. If I add the assignment and announcement in the afterTest() method instead, all queries complete successfully. But with CascadeType = CascadeType.all on the collections in the Section entity, I don't see why this should matter

I am pretty new to ORM, and have been trying to understand what is going on here for a while now so I am hoping someone with more experience can help me out. The fact that annotating the Test method with @Transactional fixes it makes me think that the tables Hibernate is generating can handle this situation of having multiple collections of entities that extend the same abstract class, but then it means that I don't understand what @Transactional means which worries me. (I have set Hibernate to automatically generate all required tables in my Spring config file using `<property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>` on my vendor adapter bean)

Thanks for the help. Sorry this question got so long for what will probably be a 2 line answer.

Let me know if you need any more pieces of my code.

Comment: Even with such a long post, there are a lot of holes that make it hard to know just what's happening there. Try to come up with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new (and unpersisted) instance of Assignment and Announcement after you persist the Section object. You can either persist the objects explicitly or add them before persisting the section instance.

```
Date sevenDaysAway = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));

section.addAssignment(new Homework(ron, new Date(), sevenDaysAway, true, "Art project 1"));
section.addAnnouncement(new Announcement(ron, new Date(), "Announcement Text"));

entityManager.persist(art);
entityManager.persist(ron);
entityManager.persist(fall11);
entityManager.persist(section);
```

Comment: That won't make a difference. They're added within the transaction, and that's all that matters.

Comment: @RyanStewart is right, it doesn't matter whether I persist the assignment before adding it or adding it to the section before the section is persisted, both cause the same error.
[I have rewritten the question to hopefully be more clear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809543/hibernate-and-spring-entity-with-multiple-members-inheriting-from-same-parent)